# How to calculate number of possible directed graphs given e edges

Tags: graph-theory

Can anyone tell me how to compute the number of possible directed graphs with no self loops, given $e$ edges. Count all possible isomorphic graphs as $1$.

For example with one edge, there is only one way (treat edge from 1 to 2 is same as edge from 2 to 1).

For the case of $2$ edges there are $4$ possible ways:

1. {(1,2),(2,1)},
2. {(1,2),(2,3)}
3. {(1,2),(3,2)}
4. {(1,2),(3,4)}.

In this case treat {(1,2),(2,1)}={(2,1),(1,2)} and {(1,2),(3,2)}={(2,1),(2,3)}. (If we proceed this way, we at most require $2\times e$ nodes for $e$ edges.)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you forgot {(1,2),(1,3)}, which brings the total for $2$ edges up to $5$.

See http://oeis.org/A053418 "Number of unlabeled directed graphs with n arcs and no isolated vertices", which begins $1, 5, 17, 80, 365, 1981,\ldots$. Sadly, I don't know of an elegant way to compute it.